Scrollbar Not Always Visible in Firefox for a Div When Idle
I have a div that contains a scrollbar, and it works fine in most browsers. The scrollbar is always visible in Chrome, Opera, and Internet Explorer. However, in Firefox, the scrollbar disappears when the content is idle, and I need it to always remain visible.
Below I added my CSS styles for my DIV
CSS
.transcript-container {
    max-height: 250px;
    overflow-y: auto;  /* I want the scrollbar to always be visible */
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #f8f9fa;
    border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
    border-radius: 8px;
    text-align: justify;
}

I've tested this across different browsers:
Chrome: Always visible
Opera: Always visible
Internet Explorer: Always visible
Firefox: Scrollbar disappears when content is idle
How can I ensure that the scrollbar remains visible in Firefox even when the content is idle?
Any help would be appreciated!
Scroll bar is not visible
Scroll bar is visible

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

What does "content is idle" mean?

When the page is not active then the scroll bar is not visible.

See this firefox implements this autohide from windows side, you wont be able to change this,atleast not from a website side, you need to act minimum as extension or a script outside of firefox. not a webpage to change this.
